# Partition By in Nested Select Returning Strange Results

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I came across a strange behavior in SQLServer 2008 that I didn't understand. I wanted to quickly just pair a unique customer with a unique payment.

Using this query, I get the results that I am expecting. Each CustomerId is paired with a different PaymentId.

```
SELECT CustomerId, PaymentId, RowNumber1, RowNumber2
FROM (
    SELECT
        c.Id as CustomerId,
        p.Id as PaymentId,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY p.Id ORDER BY p.Id) AS RowNumber1,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c.Id ORDER BY c.Id) AS RowNumber2
    FROM Customer as c
    CROSS JOIN Payment as p
) AS INNERSELECT WHERE RowNumber2 = 1

+------------+-----------+------------+------------+
| CustomerId | PaymentId | RowNumber1 | RowNumber2 |
+------------+-----------+------------+------------+
|          4 |         1 |          1 |          1 |
|          5 |         2 |          2 |          1 |
+------------+-----------+------------+------------+
```

However, if I remove the RowNumber1 column from the outer select, the results seem to change. Now every value of PaymentId is 1, even though I did not touch the inner select statement.

```
SELECT CustomerId, PaymentId, RowNumber2
FROM (
    SELECT
        c.Id as CustomerId,
        p.Id as PaymentId,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY p.Id ORDER BY p.Id) AS RowNumber1,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c.Id ORDER BY c.Id) AS RowNumber2
    FROM Customer as c
    CROSS JOIN Payment as p
) AS INNERSELECT WHERE RowNumber2 = 1

+------------+-----------+------------+
| CustomerId | PaymentId | RowNumber2 |
+------------+-----------+------------+
|          4 |         1 |          1 |
|          5 |         1 |          1 |
+------------+-----------+------------+
```

Could anyone explain to me why removing a column from the outer select causes the values in the PaymentId column to change? What other method could I use to achieve my desired goal without needing the row numbers in the result set?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because order for row_number() inside your subquery is generally not defined.
When you make a cross join, rows could be in any order

It could be:

```
CUSTOMERID PAYMENTID
         4         1    
         4         2    
         5         2    
         5         1
```

or it could be

```
CUSTOMERID PAYMENTID
         4         1    
         4         2    
         5         1    
         5         2
```

when you compute row_number in first recordset partition by CUSTOMERID, you get

```
CUSTOMERID PAYMENTID ROWNUMBER
         4         1         1  
         4         2         2
         5         2         1
         5         1         2
```

when you compute row_number in second recordset partition by CUSTOMERID, you get

```
CUSTOMERID PAYMENTID ROWNUMBER
         4         1         1  
         4         2         2
         5         1         1
         5         2         2
```

IF you wnat just pair random customers and payments, you can do this

```
with cte_cust as (
    select id, row_number() over (order by id) as row_num
    from Customer
), cte_pay as (
    select id, row_number() over (order by id) as row_num
    from Payment
)
select
    c.id as CustomerId,
    p.id as PaymentId
from cte_cust as c
    inner join cte_pay as p on p.row_num = c.row_num
```

note that if you have more customers than payments, some customers will not appear in the result (and vice versa).

[**<kbd>sql fiddle demo</kbd>**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9a4a8/18)

Comment: Is there any way to give it a hint on how to order it after a cross join so I consistently get results like my first example?

Comment: Thank you, I hadn't even thought to try doing it that way